# Export participants with Membership data

Tags: civievent, civimember, export

If I'm right it used to be possible to export participants as csv with Membership data.

But it is not there any more in 4.4 and 4.6.

Is there a way how that could be done nowadays?

We need participant info and the membership type in one export.

It is also possible that the participant has no membership.

The only solution I do see now is to create smart groups for all membership types and also a smart group for people without membership. Then go to advanced search, select 1 of these groups, select the right event, display results as participants and export the participant fields and repeat this for all the membership types and the no-member group. Then Add all these csv's to one excel with a column for the membership type.

This is cumbersome and misses one key wish: We also would like to export the membership end-date in this csv. Any solution for it?

Oh, it is a Wordpress site, otherwise I would have tried Views

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a slightly less cumbersome approach might be to create smart groups for the participants in each event for which you want to pull this information (that might be a useful thing to have in any case - for example, if you need to email your participants), and then run a membership report or search for contacts by event participant group.  You might even be able to get around the need to create multiple lists by trying the "Contribution and Membership Details" report, searching for people in your group with event fees (if you're charging for the event) and pulling the membership details for those folks.

Lesley

Comment: hmm, we do also need the participant info in the csv